# javascript function won't run onchange

Tags: javascript, onchange

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName("option");
    for (var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++){
        allSelect[i].onchange = loadLink;
    }
}

function loadLink(){
     alert("TEST");
}
```

So I'm working on this problem for a class and the functions are incredibly simple. I replaced the code needed with a simple alert because even tracking break point by point it doesn't run the loadLink() function. AllSelect is populated and are all have the onchange value with the specified code in the {}.

I have also tried putting it into the html element by hand and it still doesn't work.

Any Ideas? I'm running locally on my computer with both IE and Chrome if anyone cares to know. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Onchange belongs on the select element, not the option elements.

Comment: Attach the `onchange` handler to the `<select>` elements, not the `<option>`s.

Comment: There are some quirks with the change event on select elements. Check behaviour using the cursor keys to select an option and see what happens in IE, as it will dispatch a change event each time a new option is highlighted. Other browsers don't dispatch a change event until an option is actually selected, e.g. use cursor keys to highlight an option, the press tab (Firefox) or space (Safari) to select the option.

Answer (score 5):

The onchange event belongs on the select element, not the option elements. So:

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (var i = 0; i < allSelect.length; i++){
        allSelect[i].onchange = loadLink;
    }
}

function loadLink(){
     alert("TEST");
}
```

Comment: Haha, wonderful. The book for this class is amazing. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh my god, so a book told you to add it to the option elements?! What book is that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
    var allSelect = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
```

You are instead querying the option elements within selects in the DOM.